# It is not copying buttons when appending table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble copying buttons into an appended row:

I have a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bjqr6/37/

In the jsfiddle, if you click on the "Open Grid" link and select either "True or False" button or "Yes or No" button, it will display those buttons at the bottom.

Now turn one of those buttons on by clicking on it (button will turn green)

Now the problem is that if you click on the "Add Question" button to append you buttons into a table row, you will see it does not copy the buttons into the table row.

Does anyone know why it does not copy the buttons and append them in the row?

Comment: I just tested it in Chrome, FF and Opera, seems to be working.

Comment: @heatcode I just tested it in opera and it isn't working for me. Are you sure it is working? When you click on "Add Question", it will append a row but in the appended row you would not see the "True" or "False" button or the "Yes" or "No" button in the appended row under the "Answer" heading

Comment: The buttons show up when I click on Open Grid and choose one of them. Isn't that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: No, I mean when you append a row (click "Add Question"), it is suppose to copy the top control into the appended row, but you see in the appended row that it copies the textbox and "Open Grid" link, but it does not copy the buttons into the appended row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically added

```
var $ans = context.find('.answerBtnsOn');    
var $answer = $("<div class='answer'>Answer:<br/></div>").append($ans.val());
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Bjqr6/40/. Is this what you want?